# Any ubuntu plugin for terminal that creates a file with a basic html markup?

Tags: command-line, files, html

Like when I cd to a directory, let's say Desktop. I create a file using

```
> index.html
```

Can it be done somehow that same file has basic html markup, like html/head/body tags?

Comment: Could be a duplicate of / related to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/162617/how-can-i-automatically-add-some-skeleton-code-when-creating-a-new-file-with-vim

Comment: Maybe you should be using markdown or haml or jade or something instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an easier method: create a "template" in `~./Templates` and `cp` that to make a copy where you need it.

Comment: Hope you do not mind the edit. No need for it to be a question(=comment) ;)

Comment: Not at all. Just getting started here (clearly)